# make: *** [Util/BuildTools/Linux.mk:142: setup] Error 1

Tags: python, c++, clang++

I am trying to build Boost for Python in Ubuntu 20.04 and got an error. I am not sure what is the issue. i have clang 10 installed in the system. while trying the following error is coming:

```
Building B2 engine..

A C++11 capable compiler is required for building the B2 engine.
Toolset 'clang' does not appear to support C++11.

> clang++ -x c++ -std=c++11  check_cxx11.cpp
check_cxx11.cpp:14:10: fatal error: 'thread' file not found
#include <thread>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.


** Note, the C++11 capable compiler is _only_ required for building the B2
** engine. The B2 build system allows for using any C++ level and any other
** supported language and resource in your projects.


You can specify the toolset as the argument, i.e.:
    ./build.sh [options] gcc

Toolsets supported by this script are:
    acc, clang, como, gcc, intel-darwin, intel-linux, kcc, kylix, mipspro,
    pathscale, pgi, qcc, sun, sunpro, tru64cxx, vacpp

For any toolset you can override the path to the compiler with the '--cxx'
option. You can also use additional flags for the compiler with the
'--cxxflags' option.

A special toolset; cxx, is available which is used as a fallback when a more
specific toolset is not found and the cxx command is detected. The 'cxx'
toolset will use the '--cxx' and '--cxxflags' options, if present.

Options:
    --help                  Show this help message.
    --verbose               Show messages about what this script is doing.
    --debug                 Build b2 with debug information, and no
                            optimizations.
    --guess-toolset         Print the toolset we can detect for building.
    --cxx=CXX               The compiler exec to use instead of the detected
                            compiler exec.
    --cxxflags=CXXFLAGS     The compiler flags to use in addition to the
                            flags for the detected compiler.



Failed to build B2 build engine
make: *** [Util/BuildTools/Linux.mk:142: setup] Error 1
```

What may be issue and what can i change?

Comment: Did you install the lib(std)c++-dev packages too?

Comment: I am not sure about that. i ran the commands `sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.llvm.org/focal/ llvm-toolchain-focal main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential clang-10 lld-10 g++-7 cmake ninja-build libvulkan1 python python-dev python3-dev python3-pip libpng-dev libtiff5-dev libjpeg-dev tzdata sed curl unzip autoconf libtool rsync libxml2-dev git
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang++ clang++ /usr/lib/llvm-10/bin/clang++ 180 &&
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/clang clang /usr/lib/llvm-10/bin/clang 180`

Comment: Looks like your compiler is not using C++11 (or later) by default.

Comment: focal's `build-essential` package already comes with GCC 9. Not sure why you installed GCC 7 then? Shrug. Install `libc++-10-dev` as well and clang++ should be happy.

Comment: @Botje I installed it using `sudo apt-get install libc++-10-dev` and it was installed. Then I ran it and got the same error